# multiple database syncing in different locations in MYSQL at periodic timings

Tags: mysql, asp.net

i have a system at head office with MySQL installed. i have client machines at different locations. i need to sync all the database for example once a customer detail is entered in one client it has to be recorded to the central database and then it should synced to all other client machine. is there any MySQL service to achieve this or i have to write scripts to do it in a periodical time.

Answer (score 0):

I think not in that case you think. You can't use a MySQL replication if you write on all nodes. Then you get inconsistent data.

The only way is to write a script which sync all your data and look for new customers and add them to the main database with all relations.